# android CoordinatorLayout and SwipeRefreshLayout and RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

Here is my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="#03BCD4"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When the `RecyclerView`'s Adapter `getItemCount` is too little, the `RecyclerView` can't scroll, and the toolbar is hidden.

It is hard to show the toolbar, as it always show the `SwipeRefreshLayout` refresh status.

Is there anything I can replace that would solve the problem?

Comment: have you tried scroll view layout out after app bar layout. both swipe and recyceler view inside scroll view layout..?

Comment: i found NestedScrollSwipeRefreshLayout that implements NestedScrollingChild can solve this problem,but when the getMotionEventY is too little,it always show the SwipeRefreshLayout refresh status.

Comment: Have you found any solution?